# feature is not working in javascript slider on web server but working on localhost (menucool JavaScript Image Slider - Release v.2012.9.11)

Tags: javascript, slider

visit my website http://singrauli.co.in/ 
the image slider is working but when clicking on thumbnail it is not working and thumbnails are not being highlightined when it is active.

but this feature is working on localhost.

visit official site of this slider where all features is working http://www.menucool.com/slider/javascript-image-slider-demo2

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a guess as I don't know your local configuration but would that call be failing because your images are stored on a subdomain (therefore violating the cross-domain rule)?

> Basically, JS believes that even a subdomain such as
>   img.yourdomain.com is a different domain from www.yourdomain.com.

from [Cross Sub Domain Javascript (Ajax, Iframe, etc)](http://www.tomhoppe.com/index.php/2008/03/cross-sub-domain-javascript-ajax-iframe-etc/)